# Find size of shared memory in C shmget

Tags: c, shared-memory

I was wondering if it is possible to obtain the size of a shared memory segment in C created from `shmget` without having the size of the segment as a part of the data? I'm trying to allocate a dynamic int array and need to find the size of the array in the child process.

Main process:

```
int sizeOfArray = 3;
int shm = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(int) * sizeOfArray, IPC_CREAT | 0666);
int *a = (int*) shmat(shm, NULL, 0);
a[0] = 0;
a[1] = 1;
a[2] = 2;
if (fork() == 0) {
    char *args[3];
    char shmID[11];
    bzero(shmID, 11);
    intToString(shm, shmID); // custom function that does what the name implies
    args[0] = "slave";
    args[1] = shmID;
    args[2] = NULL;
    execvp("slave", args);
    return -1;
}

wait(NULL);
shmdt((void*) a);
shmctl(shm, IPC_RMID, NULL);
```

Child process (slave):

```
int shm = atoi(argv[1]);
int *ptr = (int*) shmat(shm, NULL, 0);
//TODO: find length of int array in shared memory
shmdt((void*) ptr);
return 0;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found that if you use `shmctl` and the `IPC_STAT` flag, you can get the number of bytes allocated to the shared memory segment. Then you can just divide it by `sizeof(int)` to get the size of your array.

```
struct shmid_ds buf;
shmctl(shm, IPC_STAT, &buf);
int length = (int) buf.shm_segsz / sizeof(int);
```